# Call a javascript function at distinct time intervals

Tags: javascript

I've created a stock ticker function and need to call it every 2 minutes.

I've succeeded in doing this with the javascript `setInterval` function, but the problem is on the first call it waits 2 minutes before calling the function, whereas I want the first load to be called right away.

```
function CallFunction() {
  setInterval("GetFeed()", 2000);
}
```

Comment: FYI, the second parameter to setInterval is measured in milliseconds - 2000 is two seconds, and you'll want 120000 for two minutes (= 120 seconds * 1000 milliseconds/second).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function CallFunction() {
        GetFeed();
        setInterval("GetFeed()", 2000);
    }
```

Comment: my 2 cents `setInterval(GetFeed, 2000);`

Answer (score 3):

```
function CallFunction() {
  GetFeed();
  return setInterval(GetFeed, 2 * 60 * 1000);
}

var id = CallFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet shown in image calls a function after every 20 seconds and it can be stopped by calling cancelRepeat() function. Hope this helps.

[image]